# Unity - Advertisment called multiple times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ads

I'm having this problem using Unity's Advertisment. Specifically after watching the video and clicking the X button to close the video, I should give the prize to the player (go to the next level). The problem is that the OnUnityAdsDidFinish function calls if (showResult == ShowResult.Finished) multiple times. What am I doing wrong? how do I call the FindObjectOfType  () .LoadNextLevel () function once; ? Thank you in advance

```
public class UnityAdsInterstitial : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsListener
{
private string gameID = "******";
//nome scelto nella DashBoard di Unity
private string interstitialID = "interstitial";

private string myPlacementId = "rewardedVideo";

public int randomHighValue = 30;

private bool TestMode = true;

private bool adsClosed = false;

public Button _button;

private void Awake()
{
    _button = GetComponent<Button>();
}

void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("Ads  start");
    _button = GameObject.Find("StartAds").GetComponent<Button>();

    _button.interactable = Advertisement.IsReady(myPlacementId);

    if (_button) _button.onClick.AddListener(ShowRewardedVideo);

    Advertisement.Initialize(gameID, TestMode);
    Advertisement.AddListener(this);
    if (adsClosed)
    {
        adsClosed = false;
    }
    
}

public void ShowInterstitial()
{
    if (Advertisement.IsReady(interstitialID) )
    {
        Advertisement.Show(interstitialID);
    }
}

public void ShowRewardedVideo()
{
    if (Advertisement.IsReady(myPlacementId))
    {
        Debug.Log("Rewarded video is Ready");
        Advertisement.Show(myPlacementId);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Rewarded video is not ready at the moment! Please try again later!");
    }
}

public void HideBanner()
{
    Advertisement.Banner.Hide();
}

public void OnUnityAdsReady(string placementdID)
{
    if (placementdID == interstitialID)
    {
        Debug.Log("InterstitialIsReady");
    }

    if (placementdID == myPlacementId)
    {
        Debug.Log("RewardedIsReady");
        _button.interactable = true;
    }

}

public void OnUnityAdsDidFinish(string placementdID, ShowResult showResult)
{
    if (showResult == ShowResult.Finished)
    {
        // Reward the user for watching the ad to completion.
        
        if (!adsClosed)
        {
            adsClosed = true;
            FindObjectOfType<LevelLoader>().LoadNextLevel();  
        }
        
    }
    else if (showResult == ShowResult.Skipped)
    {
        // Do not reward the user for skipping the ad.
    }
    else if (showResult == ShowResult.Failed)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("The ad did not finish due to an error.");
    }
}

public void OnUnityAdsDidError(string message)
{

    Debug.Log("OnUnityAdsDidError");
}
public void OnUnityAdsDidStart(string message)
{

    Debug.Log("OnUnityAdsDidStart");
}
```

Comment: This isn't a question about the Visual Studio application, so I've removed that tag for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start my investigation by checking the placement id (in case there are more placements)

1. Checking that the callback is for the proper placement id

```
    if (showResult == ShowResult.Finished && placementId == myPlacementId)
    {
        // Reward the user for watching the ad to completion.
        
        if (!adsClosed)
        {
            adsClosed = true;
            FindObjectOfType<LevelLoader>().LoadNextLevel();  
        }
        
    }
```

The second would be that I only have one active instance of `UnityAdsInterstitial`. You can check this in debug mode by the reference of the object. If more than one instance starts from somewhere else in your code, then you should just limit to one.

Comment: It could be that there are multiple instances. How do you suggest me to limit to one starting from the code I posted above? In your opinion, what would be the most correct and clean way to not have more instances? Singleton?

Comment: Depends on the outside implementation and initialization of the behavior. I never suggest singlenton as I consider it mostly an anti-pattern. I might delegate instantiation to another like a factory or dependency injection container and handle the object lifetimes from there. (like a simple factory that will always provide the same instance until it finished the job).